# Problem with htaccess and query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I'm trying to rewrite some URLs using mod_rewrite, but I'm getting different results from two similar rules. Here's my code:

**First Rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^api/(.*?)$            index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

With an input of *example.com/api/test1/test2/test3* I get the following output in PHP:

```
Array ( [p] => test1/test2/test3 )
```

**Second Rule:**

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/(.*?)$            index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$            index.php?p=$1 [L] #test
```

With an input of *example.com/test1/test2/test3* I get the following output in PHP:

```
Array ( [p] => index.php )
```

This isn't what I expected, I thought it would be `[p] => test1/test2/test3` like with the first rule. What can I do to make the results the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem? What is expected and what happens?

Comment: I want that the second rule return the same output of the first rule. Can you understand me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second rule,

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

contains a test pattern that matches what you are rewriting to (index.php). After the initial rewrite of */test1/test2/test3* to *index.php?p=test1/test2/test3*, another rewrite is performed that transforms *index.php* (with the *p=test1/test2/test3* query string) to *index.php?p=index.php*.

You should condition the rule so that this second rewrite isn't performed. One way to do this is to see if the target of the request exists:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?p=$0
```

Comment: Set as answer if this is the solution please.